# Sending zip files and keeping file paths consistent

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I have created a GUI and Database for my company.  I am trying to alpha test the program.  I made the program so that everyone would place it on their C drive so that the file paths would stay consistent. When I email the zip folder to everyone it adds an extra folder that is causing errors to the file path (I believe the error occurs during extraction?).  Does anyone know a good way to prevent this from happening?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although "xcopy deployment" is a valid method to deploy programs, it can come with complications, as you have discovered. Instead, you can create an actual installer program which is much more versatile.

For a lead-in on making an installer you can read [Create MSI installer in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286704/create-msi-installer-in-visual-studio-2017).

Make sure that the program uses locations as given in the [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) so that it is automatically adapted for any (properly-configured) Windows installation.

Other installers are available, e.g. [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), which may offer simpler or more detailed configuration of some options like replacing or keeping older files, or installing prerequisites like a required framework version.