# Deploying local database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, installation, deployment

I am making a WPF app in .netframework 4.7.2 on a local db which is mysql
I want to deploy this db local to my system to the clients machine ,exactly 6 computers
There was already a Db in ms access and I had to create a new db and insert values into it
I have modeled and designed the db on my system and also inserted the data column by column
aprox its 9000 record plus validation so there is no question of going to my clients place and replicating the process

I do not wish to voilate the guidlines but I have two questions and both are related to each other, if these still violate the guidlines please edit it out

1. is there a way to include the mysql db in like a single setup.exe thats installs everything on all the systems (i have seen this in .net core but cannot find a way in .NF)
2. the target systems are diffrent two are windows 7 another is an 8 and rest are 10 mine is also windows 10, so will this method be compatible to all ( do i have to install .net framework or MySQL on the target systems )

Comment: You need to create a setup package including the mysql installer and an application that creates the needed database content: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ & https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php & https://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/4-tools-to-create-windows-installer-packages & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/16594/how-to-create-setupinstaller-exe-file-from-visual.html & https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-ext-vs.html

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286704/create-setup-msi-installer-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: @OlivierRogier is this also backward compatible for win 8 and 7

Comment: @.graceh About what ask you that?

Comment: @OlivierRogier I am asking about the installation package can that run on older operating system like Windows 7 and will by software be able to work with it

Comment: @.graceh Just choose an installer like Inno Setup or Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects for example, and a MySQL version that support the targeted OS.